# Is it possible to create a JSON Web Token using Azure Key Vault's Keys API?

Tags: node.js, azure, jwt, azure-keyvault

I am currently using the `jsonwebtokens` package for generating signed JWTs with a RSA signing key. I was experimenting to see how I can move to **Azure Key Vault**. One way I can do is to store the private and public keys as Vault Secrets. But I noticed that there's also a Vault Keys API which generates a key in Vault and signs data which I provide it.

I've been trying with the [`@azure/keyvault-keys`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/keyvault-keys) package and this is where I've got:

```js
async signJsonWebToken(data: object, expiry: string): Promise<string> {
  const headerB64 = this.base64url(JSON.stringify(this.keyHeader), 'binary');
  const payloadB64 = this.base64url(this.getTokenData(data, expiry), 'utf8');
  const payload = `${headerB64}.${payloadB64}`;

  const key = await this.keyClient.getKey(this.KEY_NAME);
  const cryptClient = new CryptographyClient(key, new DefaultAzureCredential());

  const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');
  const digest = hash.update(payload).digest();

  const signResult = await cryptClient.sign('RS256', digest);
  const signResultB64 = this.base64url(signResult.result.toString(), 'utf8');
  const result = `${payload}.${signResultB64}`;
  this.logger.log('Key: ' + key.key);
  this.logger.log('Sign result: ' + result);
  return result;
}

private base64url(data: string, encoding: string) {
  return SBuffer
    .from(data, encoding)
    .toString('base64')
    .replace(/=/g, '')
    .replace(/\+/g, '-')
    .replace(/\//g, '_');
}

private getTokenData(data: object, expiry: string): string {
  const now = Date.now();
  const expiresIn = new Date();
  if (expiry.endsWith('d')) {
    expiresIn.setDate(expiresIn.getDate() + parseInt(expiry));
  } else if (expiry.endsWith('h')) {
    expiresIn.setHours(expiresIn.getHours() + parseInt(expiry));
  } else if (expiry.endsWith('m')) {
    expiresIn.setMinutes(expiresIn.getMinutes() + parseInt(expiry));
  }
  const tokenData = Object.assign({
    iat: now,
    exp: expiresIn.getTime()
  }, data);
  return JSON.stringify(tokenData);
}
```

The generated signed signature do not look anywhere close to what I'd usually be getting with the `jsonwebtoken` package. My intention is that I'd like to sign my tokens with Vault but would like to verify with `jsonwebtoken.verify()`. Is this even possible? What am I doing wrong in my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you use the Azure kay vault to sign jwt, we also can use Azure key vault to Verify the jwt

For example

```
 const key = await this.keyClient.getKey(this.KEY_NAME);
 const cryptClient = new CryptographyClient(key, new DefaultAzureCredential());
const util =require('util')
const base64 = require('base64url');
const JWT=""
    const jwtHeader = JWT.split('.')[0];
    const jwtPayload = JWT.split('.')[1];
    const jwtSignature = JWT.split('.')[2];
    const signature = base64.toBuffer(jwtSignature)
    const data = util.format('%s.%s', jwtHeader, jwtPayload);
    const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');
    const digest = hash.update(data).digest()
const verified =await cryptClient.verify("RS256",digest,signature)
```

Besides If you want to use `jsonwebtoken` package to verify jet, please refer to the following code

```
const util =require('util')
const base64 = require('base64url');
const forge = require('node-forge');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
async Function test{
// gerenrate jwt
const headerObj = {
        alg: 'RS256',
        typ: 'JWT'
    };
    
    const payloadObj = {
        sub: '1234567890',
        name: 'John Doe'
       
    };
    
    const encodedHeader = base64(JSON.stringify(headerObj));
    const encodedPayload = base64(JSON.stringify(payloadObj));
    const data = util.format('%s.%s', encodedHeader, encodedPayload);

    const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');
    const digest = hash.update(data).digest()
   
    
    const keyClient =new KeyClient("https://testsql.vault.azure.net/",new DefaultAzureCredential());
    const key =await keyClient.getKey("test");
    const cryptClient = new CryptographyClient(key.id, new DefaultAzureCredential());
    const signResult = await cryptClient.sign("RS256",digest)     
    const jwts =util.format('%s.%s.%s', encodedHeader, encodedPayload,base64(signResult.result));
    console.log(jwts)

// verify

// convert azure key vault ket to public key
var n =Buffer.from(key.key.n).toString("base64")   
    var e =Buffer.from(key.key.e).toString("base64")
    var publicKey = forge.pki.setRsaPublicKey(
        base64urlToBigInteger(n),
        base64urlToBigInteger(e)); 
// convert public key to pem file
     var pem = forge.pki.publicKeyToPem(publicKey);
    var d= jwt.decode(jwts,pem.toString())
    console.log(d)
}




function base64urlToBigInteger(str) {
   
    var bytes = forge.util.decode64(
      (str + '==='.slice((str.length + 3) % 4))
        .replace(/\-/g, '+')
        .replace(/_/g, '/'));
    return new forge.jsbn.BigInteger(forge.util.bytesToHex(bytes), 16);
  };
```

Comment: This is the direction where I was heading to, I guess. Thanks for the pointers. I'll try this when I head back home and update the status. :)