# Is it possible to create JWT tokens using key vault keys?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-keyvault, adal

i want to us `Key Vault` key to create JWT token and then validate it.

Im using this code:

```
public static async Task<string> SignJwt()
{
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var signinKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("this is my custom Secret key for authentication"));
    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim("id", "1") }),
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(signinKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
    };
    var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
    return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
}
```

and it works fine. I was googling a lot and found this snippet for `SigningCredentials` using Identity extension nuget:

```
new SigningCredentials(new KeyVaultSecurityKey("https://myvault.vault.azure.net/keys/mykey/keyid", new KeyVaultSecurityKey.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback)), "RS256")
{
    CryptoProviderFactory = new CryptoProviderFactory() { CustomCryptoProvider = new KeyVaultCryptoProvider() }
});
```

But it is not clear for me, what really `AuthenticationCallback` is and how to implement that and if i will be able to use that in `Azure` in web app or azure function?

Comment: AuthenticationCallback is a delegate function which accepts authority, resource,  scope and returns access token for the service.

Comment: check if this helps. 

https://vmsdurano.com/-net-core-3-1-signing-jwt-with-rsa/ (keys in configuration files)

KeyVault for OAuth2 Client Creds - https://github.com/mrochon/keyvault (keys lies in key vault)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *Firstly, a JWT token consists of 3 parts (**Header, Payload and Signature**) and all those 3 parts are **Base64UriEncoded.***
- *T*o get the Signature you need to generate header and payload, then combine them by dot.**
- *Below is the sample code to verify **JWT** using **Azure kay Vault.***

```js
const key = await this.keyClient.getKey(this.KEY_NAME);
 const cryptClient = new CryptographyClient(key, new DefaultAzureCredential());
const util =require('util')
const base64 = require('base64url');
const JWT=""
    const jwtHeader = JWT.split('.')[0];
    const jwtPayload = JWT.split('.')[1];
    const jwtSignature = JWT.split('.')[2];
    const signature = base64.toBuffer(jwtSignature)
    const data = util.format('%s.%s', jwtHeader, jwtPayload);
    const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');
    const digest = hash.update(data).digest()
const verified =await cryptClient.verify("RS256",digest,signature)
```

- *Here are few SO threads with related discussions.  [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69126059), [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63025880) and [SO3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56932302)*